# In creating an adapter for a recyclerview, why one has to append the RecyclerView.Adapter which it extends with <[NameOfAdapter].Viewholder>?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, type-parameter

In my search how to create a RecyclerView I came across several [examples](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) where the adapter of the RecyclerView is created as follows:

```
public class MyAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
...
}
```

Why is `<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>` appended here? It might be something what I think is called a type parameter (like with `List<T>` for instance), but in the documentation of `RecyclerView.Adapter` I'm not able to find a confirmation that indeed this concerns a type parameter.

Comment: A ViewHolder holds the item views and add fields (casting the view).I hope this should answer your question https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full name (packages included) is `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<VH extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder>`. So `RecyclerView.Adapter` does in fact have a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` as type parameter. This is used in the `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` methods so that these know what kind of `ViewHolder` they're dealing with.

Comment: Ah you're right, thanks, it's indeed in the full name of the class. The full name is depicted in the documentation of the class at the top where an overview is given which parent classes it's has (with this very small font that is easily overlooked :P).